# Finding the source of a request that comes to our site

Tags: php, cross-domain

I have a question related to finding the source of a request that comes to our site.

I have a PHP file that has a function and it returns a value. I want to call this function by Ajax through other sites that I have (I do not have a problem with this part).

I was wondering it is possible to check (in the PHP file) if the request for calling the PHP file or function comes only through the sites that I have and if it is not from the defined domains, it returns false.

Do we have any functions to check this matter?

I do not need client IP address, I need to know the domain that sends the request to my site and call my Php function. Do we have a mechanism to control this?

I only want my domains B and C are able to call my PHP function which is in my domain A.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: Ever heard about Cors? Learn about it and enable Cors only for the domains you want

Comment: Thank you Lelio. I do not know about it. I should search for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Most web browsers pass the `HTTP_REFERER` variable by default, but in many this behaviour can be changed to not show it or to pass something else instead. **It** **cannot be trusted**, but it is still useful...

Answer (score 1):

I have found this [link](https://www.kerstner.at/2015/02/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-for-php/) that provides a solution for implementing CORS by PHP.